# Elegant way to check if two Booleans are equal, with a caveat where False==null?

Tags: java

I'm currently just normalizing nulls to Boolean.FALSE, then doing the check. But is there some util that does this cleanly?

Refactoring to boolean is not an option as these variables come from an external object parameter, where False is equivalent to null.

Example:

```
Boolean A = null;
Boolean B = Boolean.FALSE;

if(Objects.equals(A,B)){ //should return true
...
}
```

Comment: Why would you do that? `null` and `false` (boxed or primitive) are completely different things, and signal very different behaviour. You're working with a strongly typed language: write code that returns the correct types, and throw when they can't.

Comment: Because within the business logic context, a null param should behave the same as false, it was a recently added param and previously created params are now null.

Comment: `Boolean.TRUE.equals(null)` will return false and is null save. if you want to check if a `Boolean` is true and treat null as false using the equals method of `Boolean.TRUE` is one solution.

Comment: I'm sorry to hear that, it sounds like you could do with a code cleanup because that's quite weird: if a null param is the same as false, it should be _set_ to false in the code that saves your model updates and performed your migrations, not kept `null`. That said, just write your own function `boolean isFalsish(Boolean a, Boolean b)` so you have a single place where you need to write your comparison code. Then start using that function instead of `equals`.

Comment: `Boolean.TRUE.equals(a)==Boolean.TRUE.equals(b)`

Comment: Yeah thats the approach I was going for. I was just wondering if there was an elegant way - since False/null sometimes are seen as equivalent.

Comment: @khelwood, yeah that works =)

Answer (score 1):

`Boolean.TRUE.equals(v)` will evaluate to true if `v` is `TRUE`, and false if `v` is `FALSE` or null. Using that you can compare your two `Boolean` values (considering null and `FALSE` as equivalent) like this:

```
if (Boolean.TRUE.equals(a)==Boolean.TRUE.equals(b)) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe using optionals looks nice?

```
Optional.ofNullable(A).orElse(Boolean.FALSE).equals(B)
```